# G. Books api request

Tags: jquery, api

i'm trying to make a request to the google books api and i'm not experienced at all, i don't know why isn't working maybe you could give me some advices.

My code so far:

my html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>MyBookList</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div id="search">
        <form id="bookForm">
            <label for='bookSearch'>Search for a book!</label>
            <input type="search" id="bookSearch" name="bookSearch">
            <button>Search</button>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div id="searchResult"></div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

my js file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#bookForm').submit(function(){
        const value = $('bookSearch').val();
        if(value == ''){
            alert('asd');
        } else {
            let title = '';
            let img = '';
            let authors = '';

            $.get(`https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=${value}`, function(e){
                console.log(e);
            });
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

When i console.log e it returns nothing in my console but "Navigated to file:///C:/Users/Mark/Desktop/WD/Book%20api/index.html?bookSearch=ds"

Comment: It looks like you're not doing anything from preventing your form from being submitted and reloading the page

Comment: Is there anything else in your console? Like errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are checking the wrong value in your if statement, '**search**' is not bound to any input.

I've modified your code a bit. Try this snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#bookForm').submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const value = $('bookSearch').val();
        if (value == '') {
            alert('asd');
        } else {
            let title = '';
            let img = '';
            let authors = '';

            $.get(`https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=${value}`, function (e) {
                $('#searchResult').html(e.kind);
            });
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="search">
    <form id="bookForm">
        <label for='bookSearch'>Search for a book!</label>
        <input type="search" id="bookSearch" name="bookSearch">
        <button type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
</div>

<div id="searchResult"></div>
```

Comment: I'm sorry cause i forgot to change search to value, it seems like e.preventDefault() solved 99% of the problem, now i got data in my console, but whatever the value is i only got books that have Undefined in title.

Comment: Oh, mb the line 4 should be like const value = $('#bookSearch').val(); , yep , solved, thank you so much, anyway can you explain me in 1-2 lines why the e.preventDefault() solved it ? ;d

Comment: Since you weren't preventing the default behavior of the form post, it was effectively reloading the page.  Your code was most likely executing, but the page was refreshing so you never saw it... I think! :) Happy coding!